# Как используя Cordova правильно собрать приложение для Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cordova, sdk, terminal, apt-get

Попытка собрать в Ubuntu 14.04, приложение платформы ubuntu.
Установлен ubuntu SDK и cordova-cli, nodejs разумеется тоже. Выполняется порядок действий

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ubuntu
```

И после, запуск выполнения процесса сборки, где все крашится

```
$ cordova build ubuntu
Running command: /var/www/cordova/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build 
/var/www/cordova/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/check_reqs
Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -aarmhf -f ubuntu-sdk-13.10 create
sudo click chroot -aarmhf -f ubuntu-sdk-13.10 install cmake 
libicu-dev:armhf pkg-config qtbase5-dev:armhf qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev:armhf 
qtfeedback5-dev:armhf qtlocation5-dev:armhf qtmultimedia5-dev:armhf 
qtpim5-dev:armhf qtsensors5-dev:armhf qtsystems5-dev:armhf
/var/www/cordova/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/check_reqs FAILED
Error: /var/www/cordova/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: 
Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Далее, при попытке выполнить команду

```
$ sudo click chroot -aarmhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.04 create


E: Failed to change to directory ‘/var/www/cordova/hello’: No such file or directory
I: The directory does not exist inside the chroot.  
Use the --directory option to run the command in a different directory.
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-14.04-armhf 
-- /finish.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 266, in run
return args.func(parser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 68, in create
return chroot.create(args.keep_broken_chroot)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 557, in create
self.full_name, ret_code))
click.chroot.ClickChrootException: 
Failed to create chroot 'click-ubuntu-sdk-14.04-armhf' (exit status 1)
```

дополнение для alexander barakin (далее при выполнении cordova build --device я получаю ошибку)

```
$ cordova build --device
Running command: /home/artem/cordova-project/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device
/home/artem/cordova-project/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/check_reqs
Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -aarmhf -f ubuntu-sdk-13.10 create
sudo click chroot -aarmhf -f ubuntu-sdk-13.10 install cmake libicu-dev:armhf pkg-config qtbase5-dev:armhf qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev:armhf qtfeedback5-dev:armhf qtlocation5-dev:armhf qtmultimedia5-dev:armhf qtpim5-dev:armhf qtsensors5-dev:armhf qtsystems5-dev:armhf
/home/artem/cordova-project/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/check_reqs FAILED
Error: /home/artem/cordova-project/hello/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Comment: *-aarmhf* — вот [здесь в примере](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/) стоит пробел: `-a armhf`. представления не имею, существенно это или нет.

Comment: если это действительно флаг '-а' а не название пакета, то это очень существенно! сейчас проверю)

Comment: не помогло, та же самая ошибка. А еще настораживает вот это

`$ cordova platforms ls`
`Installed platforms: ubuntu 4.1.0-dev`
`Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos`

Comment: что-нибудь не из официального репозитория *ubuntu* и не из предложенного *ppa* вы в процессе, случайно, не устанавливали?

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`
вроде бы все) может это в source.list.d смотреть надо?

Comment: *Available platforms* — ну, если посмотреть на команды, упомянутые в руководстве, на которое я приводил ссылку, то там есть такая: `cordova platform add ubuntu`

Comment: Да, поправил свой пост, в начале дописал список команд которые я уже запускал

Comment: я через некоторое время выложу инструкцию.

Comment: Отлично, буду очень надеяться что получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на всякий случай лучше удалить созданный *chroot*:

```
$ sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.04 destroy
```

и установленные пакеты:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge cordova-cli schroot click-dev
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

после этого я бы порекомендовал обновить пакеты в системе:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

а теперь заниматься установкой:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cordova-cli schroot click-dev
$ sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.04 create
```

создайте где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге пустой каталог с произвольным именем и переключитесь туда:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/cordova-project
$ cd ~/cordova-project
```

дальше — по инструкции:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add ubuntu
```

теперь надо вписать в `config.xml` (в этом же каталоге) путь к иконке:

```
<icon src="www/img/logo.png" />
```

и найти и исправить версию *DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK* в файлах `constants.js` — она должна совпадать с версией *chroot-а*. найти такие файлы можно так:

```
$ find -name constants.js | xargs grep DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK
```

теперь должно пройти нормально (на вопрос ответьте `y`):

```
$ cordova build --device
```

Comment: выполнил `find -name constants.js | xargs grep DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK`
реакции нет, далее выполнил `find -name constants.js` нашел 2 вхождения `./platforms/ubuntu/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/constants.js` и `./platforms/ubuntu/build/bin/node_modules/elementtree/lib/constants.js`. 
файлы имеют схожее содержимое но упоминания DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK нету

Comment: вот содержимое `./platforms/ubuntu/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/constants.js` 
далее `                                              
var DEFAULT_PARSER = 'sax';                             
exports.DEFAULT_PARSER = DEFAULT_PARSER;`
после редактирования так `var DEFAULT_PARSER = 'sax';                    
var DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK = '8.21';                
exports.DEFAULT_PARSER = DEFAULT_PARSER;       
exports.DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK = DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK; `

Comment: далее при выполнении `cordova build --device` я получаю ошибку `Error: missing armhf chroot`

Comment: *но упоминания DEFAULT_FRAMEWORK* — значит, `cordova` у вас копирует не то же самое, что и у меня. какая версия программы? `$ cordova -v`. у меня *5.0.0*. версия дистрибутива у вас 14.04? битность системы какая? `$ getconf LONG_BIT`.

Comment: *далее при выполнении cordova build --device я получаю ошибку* — полный вывод этой команды вставьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: система ubuntu 14.04 64-битная, cordova -v 3.5.0-0.2.6

Comment: *cordova -v 3.5.0-0.2.6* — ну вот. откуда этот файл? `$ dpkg -S $(which cordova)`

Comment: `dpkg-query: не найден путь, подходящий под шаблон /usr/local/bin/cordova`
Еще привел часть вывода в тело моего вопроса

Comment: ну, тогда на ошибки не надо и смотреть. удалите этот файл и пользуйтесь дистрибутивным, установленным из пакета *cordova-cli*. начните с `cordova create ...` в пустом каталоге и т.д. по инструкции.

Comment: не совсем понял какой именно файл?

Comment: тот, который используете. полный путь к нему можно увидеть командой `$ which cordova`. вы уже его и процитировали: `/usr/local/bin/cordova`

Comment: а! я понял, что вам не понятно. dpkg — это низкоуровневая программа для манипуляции пакетами. если она не знает о существовании какого-то файла, то, значит, файл не входит ни в один установленный пакет. а был «скачан без регистрации и смс». (истины ради, тут есть множество оговорок, но в данном случае — файл в /usr/local/bin — всё однозначно).

Comment: файл удалил, попробовал сделать от `cordova create` и получил ту же ошибку (вывод которой уже есть в вопросе). Не знаю что делать по вашему совету: пользуйтесь дистрибутивным, установленным из пакета cordova-cli

Comment: что сейчас выдают команды `$ which cordova; dpkg -S $(which cordova); cordova -v`?

Comment: а заодно и про *node*: `$ which node; dpkg -S $(which node); node -v`?

Comment: `which cordova 
/usr/local/bin/cordova`, 
`dpkg -S $(which cordova)
dpkg-query: не найден путь, подходящий под шаблон /usr/local/bin/cordova`, 
`cordova -v
3.5.0-0.2.6`, `which node
/usr/bin/node`, `dpkg -S $(which node)
nodejs-legacy: /usr/bin/node`, `node -v
v0.10.25`

Comment: так удалите файл ` /usr/local/bin/cordova`. ну или переложите куда-нибудь к себе в домашний каталог или хотя бы переименуйте.

Comment: я его удалил, но там остался еще такой - cordova-ubuntu-2.8

Comment: извините, это был файл /usr/bin/cordova, это его я удалил))

Comment: *там остался еще такой* несущественно. что сейчас показывает `$ which cordova; dpkg -S $(which cordova); cordova -v` и `$ which node; dpkg -S $(which node); node -v`?

Comment: *извините, это был файл /usr/bin/cordova* не страшно. переустановите пакет: `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall cordova-cli`

Comment: `which cordova
/usr/bin/cordova`,
`dpkg -S $(which cordova)
cordova-cli: /usr/bin/cordova`,
`cordova -v
5.0.0`, 
`which node
/usr/bin/node`, 
`dpkg -S $(which node)
nodejs-legacy: /usr/bin/node`,
`node -v
v0.10.25`

Comment: у меня на тестовой машине аналогично. попробуйте собрать новый проект по инструкции.

Comment: удалось добится результата, все запустилось, это бомба! Мой поклон вам за вашу поддержку! Рад что есть такие люди как вы! Спасибо, буду брать с вас пример!

Comment: Не пойму только, можно ли запустить это собранное приложение без Cordova?

Comment: что-то, вроде, можно. посмотрите вывод `cordova help build` и `cordova build`. кстати, у меня маленькая просьба: **не** отмечайте мой ответ «стрелочкой вверх» («ответ полезен»): хочу вот этот значок заработать — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero

Comment: хорошо, не буду, но до этого пробовал, репутации не хватает пока что)

Comment: я на будущее: надеюсь, вам здесь понравится. мы тут все пытаемся поломать сложившиеся на многих русскоязычных форумах для программистов не очень хорошие традиции. стараемся общаться вежливо, уважительно, давать конкретные ответы, а не размышления по поводу того, зачем вообще нужно автору вопроса то, о чём он спрашивает.

Comment: я тоже стараюсь придерживаться такого стиля обсуждения, однозначно поддерживаю!

Comment: Этот пост помог многим моим друзьям, но вот сейчас получилось так что на двух одинаковых машинах разный результат. Приложение не может сбилдится, выводит : `Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.04 create
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.04 install cmake libicu-dev:armhf pkg-config qtbase5-dev:armhf qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev:armhf qtfeedback5-dev:armhf qtlocation5-dev:armhf qtmultimedia5-dev:armhf qtpim5-dev:armhf libqt5sensors5-dev:armhf qtsystems5-dev:armhf 
`

Comment: а версия дистрибутивной кордовы  ниже чем 5

Comment: все зависимости были успешно установлены, но сборка обрывается

Comment: @artemtesterov, лучше задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: окей, отпишу сюда ссылкой